# Function call in -> threading macro

Tags: clojure

We need parentheses here to make a call of anonymous function

```
user=> (-> [1 2 3 4] (conj 5) (#(map inc %)))
(2 3 4 5 6)
```

Why there is no need for parentheses around `map+` and `fmap+` in these examples?

```
user=> (def map+ #(map inc %))
#'user/map+
user=> (-> [1 2 3 4] (conj 5) map+)
(2 3 4 5 6)

user=> (defn fmap+ [xs] (map inc xs))
#'user/fmap+
(-> [1 2 3 4] (conj 5) fmap+)
(2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [documentation](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3E) for the `->` and `->>` macros state that the forms after the first parameter are wrapped into lists if they are not lists already. So the question is why does this not work for `#()` and `(fn ..)` forms? The reason  is that both forms are in list form at the time the macro expands.

For example

```
(-> 3 (fn [x] (println x)))
```

gets the `(fn [x] ...)` form at expansion time, so the macro thinks "great, it's a list, I'll just insert the 3 in the second position of the `(fn ..)` list." Invoking macroexpansion, this is what we get:

```
(fn 3 [x] (println x))
```

which of course doesn't work. Similarly for `#()`:

```
(-> 3 #(println %))
```

is expanded to

```
(fn* 3 [p1__6274#] (println p1__6274#))
```

That's why we need the extra parens.