# Why is -> not taking a (fn ...)?

Tags: clojure

I have the following code that works:

```
(def *primes*
  (let [l "2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31"
        f (fn [lst] (filter #(< 0 (count (str/trim %))) lst))
        m (fn [lst] (map #(Integer/parseInt %) lst))]
    (-> l
      (str/partition #"[0-9]+")
      f
      m)))
```

If I change it to inline the filter (`f`) and map (`m`) functions to this:

```
(def *primes*
  (let [l "2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31"]
    (-> l
      (str/partition #"[0-9]+")
      (fn [lst] (filter #(< 0 (count (str/trim %))) lst))
      (fn [lst] (map #(Integer/parseInt %) lst)))))
```

it doesn't compile anymore. The error is:

`#<CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol (NO_SOURCE_FILE:227)>`

Can anyone explain this to me?

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that map and filter takes the collection as the last parameter, yet `str/partition` takes the collection as the first, so I'm trying to mix the two using `->` but currying `map` and `filter` into functions that only take one (the first) parameter for the collection to go into.

Comment: see [Function call in -> threading macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838326/function-call-in-threading-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using function declarations as function calls. the immediate (ugly) way to fix it is to replace (fn [..] ..) with ((fn [..] ...))

Comment: This is what I ended up doing

Answer (score 3):

You can mix `->` and `->>` to a certain degree.

```
(-> l
  (str/partition #"[0-9]+")
  (->> (filter #(< 0 (count (str/trim %)))))
  (->> (map #(Integer/parseInt %))))
```

But usually having problems like this is a sign that you try to do too much in one form. This simple example could be easily fixed.

```
(->> (str/partition l #"[0-9]+")
  (filter #(< 0 (count (str/trim %))))
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %)))
```

Answer (score 1):

-> is a macro.  It manipulates the code you give it, and then executes that code.  What happens when you try to use anonymous functions inline like that, is the previous expressions get threaded in as the first argument to fn.  That is not what you want.  You want them threaded in as the first argument to the actual function.

To use ->, you'd have to declare the functions beforehand, as you did in your first example.