# threading macro -> with anonymous functions

Tags: lambda, clojure, macros

I understand the `-> theading macro in Clojure applies all the provided functions provided to a given argument. However, it doesn't seem to work with anonymous functions. For example:

```
user> (-> 4 inc inc dec)
5
```

But:

```
user> (-> 4 #(+ % 1) #(- % 1) #(+ % 1))
```

Returns the error:

```
clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentVector
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
```

If someone knows a way around it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function call in -> threading macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838326/function-call-in-threading-macro)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can have anonymous functions in Clojure macros. You are having problems, because you are missing some parentheses. :) Your example is edited below.

```
(-> 4 (#(+ % 1)) (#(- % 1)) (#(+ % 1)))
```

Comment: Yes, it works now! I was afraid the macro -> didn't like anonymous functions, but simply adding the parens does the trick. Thanks

Comment: Check out `macroexpand` to know exactly why it needs extra parens to work... it is interesting stuff :)

Comment: Ankur: will do! Thanks again.

Comment: isn't this a bug?  you shouldn't need to understand implementation details to use an api.

Comment: @andrew: That's not API in typical sense of it, `->` is a macro and macro works on 'code as data' so basically the number of cases the macro needs to handle becomes huge as you can pass any s-expressions to it. In this case the macro doesn't handle this specific case.

Answer (score 32):

(this is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757945/181772) to the question i posted in comments).

the `->` macro takes each argument, making it a list if necessary (applying "raw" functions to no args - converting `myfunc` to `(myfunc)`), and then inserts the first argument to `->` as second argument in each of those lists.

so `(-> foo myfunc)` becomes `(-> foo (myfunc))` becomes `(myfunc foo)`, roughly.

this is all described in the [docs for `->`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3E).

the problem with anonymous functions is that they are generated by a reader macro as [described here (scroll down)](http://clojure.org/reader).  that means that `#(...)` is converted (*before* normal macro expansion) into `(fn [...] ...)`.  which is fine, but, critically, *is already a list*.

so the macro believes that the anonymous function is already being applied, when in fact it is encountering a function definition (both are lists).  and adding the "extra" parens - as described above in the other answer - applies the anonymous function to no args.

the reason for this un-intuitive behaviour is that the dwim (do-what-i-mean, not dwim-witted, although...) heuristic used by the `->` macro, added to allow you to supply "bare" functions rather than requiring that you apply them to no args by enclosing them in a list, is *just* a heuristic - it simply tests for a list - and is confused by the function definition created by the reader macro.

[in my bad tempered opinion, `->` is poorly implemented and should instead reject all "bare" functions, instead only accepting function applications; it would then appear more consistent.  if not, then at least the docs could be clearer, explaining the motivating *semantics* behind placing things in lists.]

Comment: Great deliberation! Which boils down IMO to sub-optimal (sloppy?) language design

Answer (score 5):

Your specific case could have been solved simply using:

```
(-> 4 (+ 1) (- 1) (+ 1))
```

where the thread first macro `->` takes care of inserting the result of the previous step as the first argument in the "current" function.

The confusion arises from the fact that `->` is not a function but a macro and the arguments are treated very differently in this case as explained by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

anynomous function is handled by reader macro, and result in fn* form. fn* form is a symbols list. The symbols list is then feeded into "->" thread macro. "->" thread maccro does not know that this fn* list should be evaluated  before morphing it, or morphing the fn* list requires gruop the operator form together first. Then, the operator form is broken.