# How to use the Clojure -> macro with an inner function

Tags: clojure

I'm a Clojure beginner and I want to understand the `->` macro

This code works:

```
(-> '(1 2 3) reverse)
```

But this doesn't even compile and I don't know how to deal with the error message:

```
user=> (-> '(1 2 3) (fn [x] (reverse x)))
```

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration quote should be a vector, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function call in -> threading macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838326/function-call-in-threading-macro)

Comment: Thank you Alex, now I know how to fix it: (-> '(1 2 3) ((fn [x] (reverse x))))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `macroexpand` and friends a lot when unexpected things start happening.  If you use these here it becomes really obvious what's going on.

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> '(1 2 3) (fn [x] (reverse x))))
(fn (quote (1 2 3)) [x] (reverse x))
```

I think seeing this it's pretty obvious that the `(quote (1 2 3)` should not be the first arg to `fn`.

We can also see that the ugly double-parens approach fixes it:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(-> '(1 2 3) ((fn [x] (reverse x)))))
((fn [x] (reverse x)) (quote (1 2 3)))
```

Side note that tripped me up: you have to use `macroexpand-1` to get a result here.  If you use `macroexpand` or `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all` it'll blow up (with your exception) after the first expansion, since `fn` itself is a macro, and is being called with bad syntax after the first expansion.